# ¿Como crear una consulta personalizada usando JPA?

Tags: java, sql, postgresql, java-swing, jpa

estoy migrando una aplicacion de Java Swing a JavaFX y por favor si alguien pudiese ayudarme a lo siguiente:

**Uso base de datos PostgreSQL.**

En SQL nativo tengo ésta consulta que funciona perfecto:

```
SELECT count(t.idremision) as entregados, COUNT(*)-count(t.idremision) as pendientes, 
e.identrada, c.nombrecliente, ciu.nombreciudad, e.lote, e.fecharecepcion::date, e.fecharegistrado,
e.contrato, e.representante FROM transformador t
LEFT JOIN despacho d ON d.iddespacho=t.iddespacho
LEFT JOIN remision r ON r.idremision=t.idremision
INNER JOIN entrada e ON e.identrada=t.identrada
INNER JOIN cliente c ON c.idcliente=e.idcliente
INNER JOIN ciudad ciu ON e.idciudad = ciu.idciudad
GROUP BY c.idcliente, ciu.idciudad, e.identrada
ORDER BY fecharecepcion DESC;
```

[image: Modelo Entidad relación]

Como podrán ver, por cada registro en la tabla **entrada** generalmente hay  mas de un registro en la tabla **transformador** asociado...

Ejemplo:

Entrada 1 -> Total 20 .... resto de columnas de la tabla entrada y las otras asociadas...

Entrada 2 -> Total 15 .... resto de columnas de la tabla entrada y las otras asociadas...

Entrada 3 -> Total 130 ....  resto de columnas de la tabla entrada y las otras asociadas...

Hay una columna llamada **idremision** que se le hace un UPDATE cuando el transformador se entrega, y no todos se entregan al mismo tiempo, es decir que ésa columna puede ser 0 o mayor que 0 . Es 0(cero) cuando no se ha entregado, y es mayor a 0(cero) cuando se le asigna el ID de una factura desde otra tabla...

Yo lo que necesito es éste mismo resultado que muestro en la imagen:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

pero sin SQL nativo si es posible, sólo con JPA o JPQL nosé exactamente muy bien.

Por defecto JPA me creó una clase con éste codigo:

```
private List<Entrada> findEntradaEntities(boolean all, int maxResults, int firstResult) {
        EntityManager em = getEntityManager();
        try {
            CriteriaBuilder cb = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
            CriteriaQuery cq = cb.createQuery();
            cq.select(cq.from(Entrada.class)).orderBy(cb.desc(cq.from(Entrada.class).get("fecharecepcion")));            
            Query q = em.createQuery(cq);
            if (!all) {
                q.setMaxResults(maxResults);
                q.setFirstResult(firstResult);
            }
            return q.getResultList();
        } finally {
            em.close();
        }
    }
```

Aunque necesita ordenar por fecha y me tocó añadir ésta parte que no estaba:

```
cq.select(cq.from(Entrada.class)).orderBy(cb.desc(cq.from(Entrada.class).get("fecharecepcion")));
```

Espero por favor me puedan ayudar a como crear ésta misma consulta de alguna forma con JPA, o JPQL, no entiendo muy bien éste framework, hasta ahora estoy empezando. Si alguno me puede asesorar y aconsejarme usar otro metodo para realizar consultas a base de datos lo agradeceré...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes hacerlo escribiendo tu consulta en `String`, teniendo tu consulta en ese `String` puedes llamarla con `createNativeQuery`, puedes mandarlos parámetros que tienes solo tienes que concatenarlos donde tengas tu `where`, como este ejemplo que te dejo con tus datos:

```
private List<Entrada> findEntradaEntities(boolean all, int maxResults, 
int firstResult){
    EntityManager em = getEntityManager();

String queryStringBaseAll = "SELECT count(t.idremision) as entregados, COUNT(*)-  
count(t.idremision) as pendientes, 
e.identrada, c.nombrecliente, ciu.nombreciudad, 
e.lote, e.fecharecepcion::date, e.fecharegistrado,
e.contrato, e.representante FROM transformador t
LEFT JOIN despacho d ON d.iddespacho=t.iddespacho
LEFT JOIN remision r ON r.idremision=t.idremision
INNER JOIN entrada e ON e.identrada=t.identrada
INNER JOIN cliente c ON c.idcliente=e.idcliente
INNER JOIN ciudad ciu ON e.idciudad = ciu.idciudad
GROUP BY c.idcliente, ciu.idciudad, e.identrada
ORDER BY fecharecepcion DESC ";

List<Entrada> listEntradas = null;
    try {

        listEntradas = em.createNativeQuery(queryStringBaseAll, 
     Entrada.class)
                .getResultList();
    } catch (Exception ex) {

    }

    if (listEntradas  == null) {
        listEntradas  = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    return listEntradas ;

}
```

Comment: Voy a intentarlo ya mismo y te comento

Comment: @Nelson Castiblanco ok si tienes dudas o algún problema me lo comentas

Comment: Cacaho GRACIAS! Ya lo hice, y la consulta funciona bien, pero como puedo mostrar las cantidades en el TableView<Entrada>...El modelo Entrada no tiene los atributos que obtengo de la clausula count(t.idremision), pues sólo es una sumatoria.. Debería agregarlos al modelo Entrada ? Pues en el TableColumn el metodo setCellValueFactory() me pide como parametro el valor que se debe mostrar en ésa columna... Pues en JavaFX se hace así, tu entenderás......

Comment: Si puedes agregarlo al modelo de entrada como @trasient o puedes crear una tabla temporal con los datos que necesitas eso lo harías en otro modelo pero con campos como estos que necesitas mostrar

Comment: No quiero ser cansón y parecer como muchos programadores que quieren que todo se lo haga... Pero sabes que estoy notando... Que el metodo findEntradaEntities() me retorna una lista de Entradas, pero ése modelo Entrada son de tipo  @Entity, las creadas automaticamente (en mi caso desde el IDE NetBeans), y en JavaFX debo usar modelos con atributos de tipo SimpleIntegerProperty, y cualquier otro pero que sean Property... Tendría que modificar el metodo findEntradaEntities() para que me retorne Entradas que sean de clases nativas propias para uso en JavaFX

Comment: Si es como tu tabla en la base de datos solo que para que la entienda el contenedor le pone @entity ahi solo modificas si necesitas que haga algún comportamiento la tabla